# Install ScientificPython

Tags: python

I am in between install rnnlib following this [link](https://github.com/szcom/rnnlib). It describes one of the dependency as **ScientificPython(not scipy).**

I have been googling but no luck finding the correct module to install. Anyone any idea what this might be.

Comment: According to this https://sourceforge.net/p/rnnl/wiki/Home/ you can download the program from here:https://sourcesup.renater.fr/projects/scientific-py/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [sourceforge.net/p/rnnl/wiki/Home](http://sourceforge.net/p/rnnl/wiki/Home) you can download the program from http://sourcesup.renater.fr/projects/scientific-py